# Visualizar Imagem Selecionada jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html5

Estou fazendo meu TCC e ele será sobre processamento de imagens. Estou tendo dificuldade com a parte web, e queria saber como eu faço para carregar a imagem selecionada no input file aparecer na página. Aqui está meu código:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".Open").change(function (index) {
        if ($('input[type=file]').eq(index).val() != "") {               
            $('#Tela').attr('src', $(this).val());
        }
    });
});
</script>
 <fieldset class ="Img">
  <img id ="Tela" Name ="Tela"></img>
  <input type ="file" name="Arquivo" class="Open"/> 
 </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alterei certos aspectos no código Javascript.

HTML:

```
<fieldset class ="Img">
  <input type ="file" id="Arquivo" name="Arquivo" class="Open"/>  
  <img id ="Tela" Name ="Tela"></img>
</fieldset>
```

Javascript:

```
function enviar_imagem(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
     var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
          $('#Tela').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#Arquivo").change(function(){
  enviar_imagem(this);
});
```

Veja uma demonstração nesse [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vacom/etwpg44s/1/)

Comment: Obrigado ajudou sim